# How to make iimage fill screen and button by its side

Tags: c#, layout, xamarin.forms

Hello I have this layout where I have a picture of a body and by its side I have some buttons with some of the parts of the body(e.g, Head,arms,legs) but I'm having trouble fixing the buttons on the same row as the picture. The buttons stay as the same size as the picture what I wanna do is have the buttons on the side of the pic, like in the example. 
[image]

I don't know if another kind of layout is more appropriate for this situtation.

here is my code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/> <!--coluna 0-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>  <!--coluna 1-->
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50*"/> <!--linha 1-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/> <!--linha 2-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/> <!--linha 3-->                   

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="corpo_cortado.png"/>
                <Button Text="Cabeça" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Button Text="Torso"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Thank you!

**correct result:**

From the comments I managed to make it work. What I did was. I created two stack Layout with vertical orientation and put each one in one column.Here some sample:

```
<StackLayout>
            <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/> <!--coluna 0-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>  <!--coluna 1-->
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50*"/> <!--linha 1-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/> <!--linha 2-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/> <!--linha 3-->                 

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="corpo_cortado.png"/>                    

                 </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Button Text="Cabeça" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: it would help if you showed us the code/xaml for what you've already tried

Comment: yes,sorry I forgot to add the XAML.

Comment: You can use RowSpan and ColSpan to make elements occupy more than one row/col

Comment: I've tried that, but the size of the button is still the same size as the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Grid Row-0, Column-1, take a Stack Layout with vertical orientation, and place two buttons inside that Stack Layout, that will place image for Row-0, Column-0 and buttons for Row-0, Column-1.
Still you need code for sample let me know.
Hope this may solve your issue.